# How Can I luks encrypt the root and swap partition on a Fedora ARM Server?

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, encryption, luks, arm

On every graphical Linux installation I've used there is typically a checkbox to enable luks encryption. Problem is the installation is different, whereas typically you get a bootable .iso or .img the current release for the fedora server is a .raw.xz where if I understand correctly, the partitions are premade.

The only ways I have seen so far to install a .raw image is using `dd` or `fedora-arm-installer`. After using the `dd` command I never saw a setup option to enable luks, I was thinking I might be able to preconfigure the block device using a combination of `cryptsetup` commands but I'm stuck because I dont know how to specify the root/swap/boot partitions using a raw image. I've looked through the options of `fedora-arm-image-installer` but there doesn't seem to be support to target specific partitions

Have I overlooked a solution or is luks support not yet implemented on the relatively new Fedora ARM? I've looked through various encryption docs but I feel like I keep circling back to specifying partitions problem.

Edits:

- I'm trying to set this up on a Raspberry Pi 3
- I could not get past boot using the suggested fedora server arm iso ( got to grub but then stuck at grub recovery shell )
- I would be open to alternative encryption methods as long as it can be rebooted from ssh and covers the root and swap partitions

Comment: Have you tried the [Fedora ARM install ISOs](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/29/Server/armhfp/iso)?

Comment: I have not, I'm surprised an ISO is not listed on arm.fedoraproject.org . I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: What is your device and how are you booting it? You seem to be describing legacy ARM devices which don't boot with UEFI; newer ARM devices which boot with UEFI are installed and booted virtually the same way as x86_64 systems.

Comment: Ah sorry for the missed details, the device is a Raspberry pi 3. It would boot off a MicroSD card, with no preference on the boot loader . I'm pretty 'green' on technical side of hardware, if I understand you correctly there's a chance I might get away with x86 image if the pi supports UEFI?

Comment: Sorry, the RPi 3 is one of the ARM64 devices which doesn't boot with UEFI.

Comment: Thanks anyways for the suggestion Michael, and no luck with the ISO Graceful.  I used linux live to make it bootable but I got as far as grub and my only path was to a grub recovery shell.